# Suffix automaton algorithm to find occurrences of substrings

Tags: algorithms, automata, strings, substrings

Here is an attached link to a problem, the [Substring query problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/SUBQUERY%29)
that I am trying to solve. It requires the use of suffix automaton,but I could not understand  what is a suffix automaton. Can anybody explain.

Comment: Did you search the web for explanation? What did you find? You should edit your questions more carefully: the link did not show, and you did not bother with capital letters. Linguistic mistakes are understandable, as not all users have English as main language, but some efforts at good presentation are expected.

Comment: @babou. To be fair to the OP, I spent some time looking for a definition of suffix automata that would be comprehensible to a newcomer. There are plenty of hits discussing SAs, especially (no surprise) in the context of string search and suffix trees, but I didn't find a succinct description of how one would construct an SA. Perhaps I didn't look hard enough, but that impression is what led to my posting an answer.

Comment: @RickDecker I was not criticizing the OP for not finding a good definition, but not giving any hint of his attempts and of what had gone wrong. Actually, it was not even criticism, but just questions.

Answer (score 5):

Given a FA $M$ accepting a language $L$, a *suffix automaton* is one which accepts the language of all suffixes of strings in $L$. In other words for a language $L$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, 
$$
\operatorname{SUFFIX}(L)=\{y\mid\exists x\in\Sigma^* \ (xy\in L)\}
$$ 
For example, if $L$ is the language denoted by the regex $ab^*a$ we'll have $L=\{aa, aba, abba, \dots\}$. A finite automaton accepting $L$ is illustrated below. (Note that we could eliminate state 3 and still accept the same language.)

[image]

The suffixes of $aa$ are $aa, a,\epsilon$, the suffixes of $aba$ are $aba, ba, a, \epsilon$ and we'll have 
$$
\operatorname{SUFFIX}(L)=\{\epsilon, a, aa, ba, aba, bba, \dots \}
$$
in other words, the suffixes of $L$ will be denoted by the regex $ab^*a+b^*a+a+\epsilon$

It turn out that the suffix language of a regular language is itself regular. Given a FA $M$, it's easy to construct a FA $M'$ that accepts $\operatorname{SUFFIX}(L(M))$: just add a new start state $s$ to $M$ and connect $s$ to each state of $M$ by $\epsilon$-transitions, as in the figure below:

[image]

The idea here is that for every accepting path in $M$, we've designed $M'$ so that it jumps to an intermediate state in the accepting path and so will accept any suffix of the original language. From $M'$ the standard NFA-to-DFA construction, found in any intro theory text, can be used to construct a DFA from $M'$. Applied to our example, we obtain the following equivalent DFA:

[image]

This, by the way, isn't the smallest equivalent DFA: we could merge states 1 and 6 into one, giving a 5-state DFA whose language is the suffix language of the original FA $M$.

---

The algorithmic intricacies of eliminating $\epsilon$-moves from the suffix automaton $M'$ can be avoided by a different construction using the same idea:

```
1. M' will have all the states and transitions of M.
2. Add a new start state, s, to M'. This new state will be a final state.
3. for every state, p, of M:
      for every state, q, of M and every character, a, in the alphabet of M:
         if we have a transition in M where (q, a) --> p:
            add the transition (s, a) --> p to M'
```

Graphically, if we have an arrow labeled $a$ coming into a state $p$, and we could have reached $p$ when processing a string "$\dots a$", we'll skip all the earlier parts of the input and go directly from the new start state to $p$ on seeing an $a$.

Here's an example of the construction, using our original FA. Of course, we still might generate a NFA, as we do here, but at least we haven't used $\epsilon$-moves in the construction.

[image]